# radiobutton is selected PHP

Tags: php, radio-button

Why does this not work or am I just being stupid? It does not print anything, the page looks exactly the same after I click the button (I have the `<form>` and everything in my actual code)

```
<html>

<input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "male">
<input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "female">

<input type="radio" name = "race" value = "asian">    

<?php
if(isset($_POST["Button"]))
{

if(($_POST["gender"] == "male") && ($_POST["race"] == "asian"))
{
 echo "you are male and asian";
}

}
?>

</html>
```

The whole area of code that has to do with it looks like this:

```
<html>
<center>
<body>

<form method=post action= "">
<br>
<br>
Name: <input type="text" name="username">
<br>
<br>
<br>

I am:

<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "male"> Male &nbsp; &nbsp;

<input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "female"> Female
<br>
<br>
</form>




<form method=post action= "">

Ethnicity:

<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name = "race" value = "asian">Asian
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name = "race" value = "black">Black
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name = "race" value = "white">White
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Button" value = "Who will I marry?">


</form>

<?php


if(isset($_POST["Button"]))
{

if(($_POST["gender"] == "male") && ($_POST["race"] == "asian"))
{

?>
congrats!
<?
}
}



?>

</center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please show form tag. I think you are using `GET` method.

Comment: why you are using two form??

Comment: Because if I use one form won't the radiobuttons all be in one group? Therefore I can only choose one out of male, female, asian, white, and black.

Comment: Ok, nevermind I take that back ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have two different Form tags, instead One Form with all Fields.

Comment: but if I use one form won't the radiobuttons all be in one group? Therefore I can only choose one out of male, female, asian, white, and black.

Comment: No because of the different names

Answer (score 0):

you are using two different form and referring from different form elements. use single form for this like this edit. and use `method="post"` instead of `method=post`

```
<form method="post" action= "">

Name: <input type="text" name="username">


I am:

<input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "male"> Male &nbsp; &nbsp;

<input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "female"> Female



 Ethnicity:

<input type="radio" name = "race" value = "asian">Asian
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name = "race" value = "black">Black
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name = "race" value = "white">White
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Button" value = "Who will I marry?">


</form>
```

Comment: but if I use one form won't the radiobuttons all be in one group? Therefore I can only choose one out of male, female, asian, white, and black.